# Views appearing in view controller when they are not in the storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel, ios8

Not 100% sure how to describe this. My storyboard does not contain labels, but when I run the program, on either the simulator or on my iOS device, there are labels there. I did place labels on the view at one point, but then I deleted then, but they are still appearing when I run the app.[image: Image showing whats happening]

Comment: You have two manage your cards scenes in the storyboard. I would recommend checking that a checkin merge or something like that has not created duplicates of the view controller you edited.

Comment: Definitely no checkin merge. I've cleaned it as well with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me in the past when I also renamed or reorganized the storyboard/xib. Try deleting the app from your device (clear all content on the simulator) and re-run. Xcode isn't always good at identifying when a file was modified, and on debug builds it only deploys modified files.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't seemed to get rid of the issue. It is utterly bizarre!

Comment: Have you tried deleting the storyboard and recreating it? I know that really sucks, but I've had to do that once when there was some hidden (and broken) outlet connection that was causing a crash on every run.